# Api call from another api call Error converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to do an api call from another api call in this code but I keep getting 
Error:  Converting circular structure to JSON

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const config = require('config');
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const axios = require('axios');
const CircularJSON = require('circular-json');

//  @router     POST api/couriers/couriersPlease
//  @desc       Test route
//  @access     Private
router.post('/couriersPlease/', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const apiId = config.get('couriersPlease.id')
        const apiKey = config.get('couriersPlease.key')

        // Encode api id and key to base64 for couriers please request
        const encodedString = new Buffer.from(apiId + ':' + apiKey).toString('base64');

        const apiConfig = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedString}`
            }
        };

        const body = CircularJSON.stringify(req.body);
        console.log('Body:', body);

        const response = await axios.post('https://api-test.couriersplease.com.au/v2/domestic/quote', body, apiConfig);

        res.json(response);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error: ', err.message);
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I checked through answers here but after hours I am still stuck,
I have tried JSON.stringify and even circular-json but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What does console.log(req.body) log?

Comment: @solooo7 A stringified json object - {"fromSuburb":"Melbourne","fromPostcode":3000,"toSuburb":"Sydney","toPostcode":2000,"items":[{"quantity":10,"length":10,"height":10,"width":100,"physicalWeight":1.3},{"quantity":2,"length":10,"height":53,"width":22,"physicalWeight":8}]}

Comment: Do you use body-parser middleware?

Comment: Yep, is that causing this issue? If so how do I get around it?

Comment: No. body-parser isn't the issue. I was making sure you have it

Comment: Remove `new` from `Buffer.from()`

Comment: Done, doesn't change anything. the authentication is fine its just the body that is giving me the error. Works fine in postman, its just when I fetch the data from my own server and try to post it to the couriers please api I keep getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 res.json(response);
```

should be

```
 res.json(response.data);
```

Feel so stupid now haha